# Right margin with two lines: is this something to be concerned about?

Tags: margins

MWE [note, this must be compiled via **XeLaTeX**]:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[showframe, top=0.5 in, bottom=0.5in, left=1in, right=1in, includehead, includefoot, headheight = 13.6pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}

%%titlename - CHANGE THE TITLE HERE!
\newcommand{\titlename}{\text{Some Title}}

%headers, footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancyplain} %header
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\fancyhead[LO, RE]{\titlename}
\fancyhead[RO, LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}%header line
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}%footer line

\fancyfoot[L]{\footnotesize{Left Blah}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\footnotesize{Right Blah}} %for 11pt, \footnotesize is 9pt.

%headers, fo

%item indent amount
\newcommand{\itemamount}{0.5in}
\newcommand{\indentamount}{0.4in}

%%exam stuff
\usepackage[load-headings]{exsheets} %need to have exsheets.cfg in the same folder
\SetupExSheets{
  headings = runin-nr ,
  headings-format = \normalsize ,
  counter-format = 1-qu. %1-question number. is the counter format. 
}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\newlist{choices}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[choices]{itemjoin = \hspace{0.75in},before=\hspace{0.125in},label=(\Alph*)}
%%exam stuff

%Times New Roman Font
\renewcommand\rmdefault{ptm}
%Times New Roman Font

\begin{document}
\setlength\parindent{\indentamount}
\begin{question}[type = exam]
\hspace{0.125in}Here's a question.
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\setlength\itemindent{\itemamount}
\item 
\item 
\end{enumerate}
\end{question}

\begin{choices}
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\end{choices}
\end{document}
```

I have to conform to the following margins: 0.5 inches top and bottom, and 1 inch on left and right sides. Headers and footers must be outside of the margins. With the code above, I get the following image [the red part is my doing]:
[image]

**Why are there two lines on the right**? If we were to extend this to the second page, similarly, we would get two lines on the left.

**On this first page, would any content be contained to the left of the line immediately to the left of the line circled in red**? This is my main concern.

Comment: Are you aware that you are using the `showframe` in the optional section of the geometry package? That space is left there to ensure that you have space for stuff in the margins. Why it switches from left to right its because you are using the twoside option for articles; hence, odd-even page perspective.

Comment: @azetina - I am aware that I am using the `showframe` option. This is merely for verification that whatever I type in will meet the margin requirements. What do I do if I do *not* want that space there?

Comment: Check page 2 of the geometry documentation. It makes reference to what you call the `marginparsep`. Try the following `marginparsep=0pt` in the optional section of the geometry package declaration.

Comment: @azetina - Thank you! Very much appreciated. If you would like to post an answer, I will give you a +10. :)

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want? It sounds like you might want to prevent margin notes, while azetina's answer will just make them run up into the text block if they are present.

Comment: @PaulGessler - Basically... I don't want anything in the margin whatsoever. Would this work?

Comment: Well there was nothing in the margin to begin with, assuming you don't plan to leave `showframe` active for the final document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Referencing the [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package documentation,

> `marginparsep` modifies `\marginparsep`, separation between body and
>   marginal notes.

Hence setting `marginparsep=⟨length⟩` to, say `0pt` would make this separation zero.

```
\usepackage[showframe, 
            marginparsep=0pt, 
            top=0.5in, 
            bottom=0.5in, 
            left=1in, 
            right=1in, 
            includehead, 
            includefoot, 
            headheight=13.6pt]{geometry}
```

Here are is an image for reference.

[image]